# Reading the registry

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

My development machine is a VirtualBox with Window Server 2008 R2. 
We are using CRM2011 with roll-up 12.
For my development I use framework 4

From CRM I call an aspx-page, this page contains a grid with records I can select. After I made a selection, I press a button and passes the selection to an assembly. This assembly has a function that checks if a certain key in the registry is available. If so it continues, if not it returns.

The problem I'm facing here is that I receive an error trying to read the registry using OpenSubKey() telling me that I'm not authorized to do so. I use code below to retrieve the key. The assembly is not signed. Signing the assembly doesn't change the result.

```
RegistryKey localKey = null;
if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
    localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser,  RegistryView.Registry64);
}
else
{
    localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);
}
```

Doing the same thing from a console application using the same assembly is giving no problems.

Regards,
Martin

Comment: The problem is solved. It had to do with the userrights. The testprogram was run under adminstrator right while the other program was run under a crm-user rigths.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your ApplicationPool identity has read access to the registry key in question.

Check what User your Application Pool is using in IIS then open the registry key in Regedit and check the permissions.